# How can I return data from a Matrix field in random order?

Tags: matrix, random, ordering

I have a slideshow with slide data managed in a Matrix field. How would I go about randomizing the data returned in the template so the slides show in a different order on each page load?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can either have MySQL select the blocks in a random order using [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

```
{% set blocks = entry.myMatrixField.order('RAND()') %}
```

Or you can shuffle the blocks from Twig instead, using Craft’s [shuffle()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions#shuffle) function:

```
{% set blocks = shuffle(entry.myMatrixField) %}
```

There’s not a major performance difference either way in most cases, however if you also want to *limit* the number of blocks, each method will give you different results.

For example, this will pick 3 blocks at random out of the entire set:

```
{% set blocks = entry.myMatrixField.limit(3).order('RAND()') %}
```

But this will always pick the first 3 blocks, and those 3 blocks will be displayed in a random order:

```
{% set blocks = shuffle(entry.myMatrixField.limit(3)) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two options for accomplishing this:

```
{% for block in shuffle(entry.matrixField) %}
```

or

```
{% for block in shuffle(entry.matrixField.find()) %}﻿
```

Comment: I think these are very much the same. `entry.matrixField.find()` explicitly returns an array, but `shuffle()` will convert to an array anyway